# using git pull/push via sftp-only connection

Tags: git, curl, sftp, ftps

I need to synchronize a git repository between two host, which are only able to talk to each other via a dedicated sftp-only server.

As far as I see git comes with an ftps but no sftp helper.

According to `man gitremote-helpers`:

```
   Git comes with a "curl" family of remote helpers, that handle various transport
   protocols, such as git-remote-http, git-remote-https, git-remote-ftp and
   git-remote-ftps. They implement the capabilities fetch, option, and push.
```

According to `man curl` curl supports both ftps and sftp:

```
   curl is a tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of the supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS,
   LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP).  The command is designed to work without user interaction.
```

As curl understands both protocols and both should at the end offer pretty much the same features, is there any good reason why there is a helper for ftps but none for sftp?

I currently thinking about implementing my own `git-remote-sftp` similar to the `git-remote-testgit`. Is there a better way I am missing?

Comment: Could you use a remote repository (e.g., self-hosted or bitbucket or something) as a staging point?  That is, on `hostA` run `git push` to the remote, and on `hostB` run `git pull` to pull the updates from the remote.

Comment: No, the hosts live in different production networks. Communication is only possible using the dedicated sftp server.